# In Pandas, How do you create a column by sequence of the iterative next occurrence of items in a group

Tags: python, pandas

In Pandas, How do you create a column by sequence of the iterative next occurrence of items in a group

I have this data:

```
import io
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO("""Name,Team\nWill,DEN\nMark,SEA\nBob,MIA\nWill,DEN\nWill,DEN\nMark,SEA\nWill,DEN\nWill,DEN\nBob,MIA\nMark,SEA\n"""))
df

   Name Team
0  Will  DEN
1  Mark  SEA
2   Bob  MIA
3  Will  DEN
4  Will  DEN
5  Mark  SEA
6  Will  DEN
7  Will  DEN
8   Bob  MIA
9  Mark  SEA
```

And i'm trying to get the Sequence of the occurence of every name or team, like this:

```
   Name Team  Sequence
0  Will  DEN         1
1  Mark  SEA         1
2   Bob  MIA         1
3  Will  DEN         2
4  Will  DEN         3
5  Mark  SEA         2
6  Will  DEN         4
7  Will  DEN         5
8   Bob  MIA         2
9  Mark  SEA         3
```

I tried cummin, but this just gives each name a unique index for each name ( which is useful for other things, but not this task ):

```
df.reset_index().groupby('Name')['index'].cummin()

0    0
1    1
2    2
3    0
4    0
5    1
6    0
7    0
8    2
9    1
```

So i'm stuck and am asking if anyone has a way to accomplish this task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have `cumcount`

```
df.groupby(list(df),sort=False).cumcount()+1
0    1
1    1
2    1
3    2
4    3
5    2
6    4
7    5
8    2
9    3
dtype: int64
```

Comment: Looking at the documentation, for my usecase i can do this with simply: df.groupby('Name').cumcount() +1   Once again, thank you for pointing me to this useful function